# How do I add a new, valid tag when I don't have enough reputation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, asking-questions

I'd like to post a question on StackOverflow, but I think I should be able to tag it with [java](/questions/tagged/java) [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) [unit-testing](/questions/tagged/unit-testing) [fest](/questions/tagged/fest). Poor me, there is no [fest](/questions/tagged/fest) tag; There is [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) and [testing](/questions/tagged/testing), I'm certainly not sure this is the **right** thing to do, so figure I'll start here.

**Edit** Question located here: [When is the right time to call robot.cleanUp()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4390533/2598)

Comment: Added your tag.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and post your question, link to it here, and I'll add the `fest` tag for you.  (Or one of the other nice, helpful people will beat me to it.)