# What should I do when I'm asking a question that needs a new tag, but I don't have enough rep?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today, I asked my first question on WebApps.SE: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76126/could-not-find-driver-error-when-registering-at-ghtorrnt-org-dblite. (I'm fairly active on other SE sites.) My question was about a web app that didn't have a tag created for it yet, and since I don't have 300 rep on the site, I wasn't able to create the appropriate tags. Looking over the list of tags already on the site, none of them looked like they would have been appropriate for my question.

What is the right course of action in this situation?

Comment: Not a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94436/creating-a-new-tag-before-you-have-enough-rep This question is about how it looks like you can add tags by putting anything you want in your favorite tags list, not using the correct tag when you can't create tags.

Comment: Duplicate, but unsatisfactory: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71705/how-do-i-add-a-new-valid-tag-when-i-dont-have-enough-reputation This older question asks the same thing I am, but the only answer given doesn't help me or anyone besides the OP. It says that an SE user with enough rep added the necessary tag for the OP's specific situation, but doesn't give the general advice I'm looking for.

Comment: True, I voted to close the older as duplicate of this one, since we got better answer(s) here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pick the best tag you can find, and leave a comment under the post asking someone to create the tag you think it should have. If a high-rep/experienced user agrees, they'll create it and edit it into your question.

Answer (score 4):

You have a number of options

- Go to the sire meta and request the tag be added to the question.
- Drop into the site chat and see if anyone is around and will do it for you.
- Flag for moderator attention.

Comment: For a site that you've never visited before, imo these measures are all slightly overkill.  But maybe that's just me.

Comment: And, if you have just 1 reputation, the first two are impossible anyway.

Comment: I've seen all 3 of those methods used.

Comment: Ugh. Don't flag for moderator attention. Save that for things only Moderators can do.

Comment: @AlE.If you can't post on meta and can't chat then your options are limited.